# All values of $z$ s.t. $e^z= 1+\sqrt{3}i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find all values of $z$ such that $e^z= 1+\sqrt{3}i$ and am getting stuck.

I know 
$$e^z=e^{x+iy}$$

from this I've done

$$e^{z}=e^x\cos(y)+e^x\sin(y)i=1+\sqrt{3}i$$

giving that

$$e^x\cos(y)=1$$
$$e^x\sin(y)i = \sqrt{3}i$$

but can't find a value for $y$ in the second equality.

Comment: For $y=\pi/3$, we have $\cos(y)=1/2$ and $\sin(y)=\sqrt3/2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\lvert1+i\sqrt{3}\rvert=2$. And that $\lvert e^{x+iy}\rvert=e^x$. This tells you immediately what $e^x$ must be, and should simplify your calculations for $y$.